# VBA Simplify code by modifying For i Next i

Tags: vba, excel

I am in the process of simplifying a series of statements which are unnecessarily complex. I wish to simplify the below example using a For i procedure, but I am unsure how to increase the scope of my statement to affect the visibility of more objects on the sheet (this may be an easy solve that I am missing somehow, tunnel vision may be in effect today).

Example:
Sheet1 contains 135 chart objects, which are labeled in the following pattern:

```
A1Z
A2Z
A3Z
A4Z
A5Z
A6Z
A7Z
A8Z
A9Z

B1Z
B2Z
B3Z
B4Z
B5Z
B6Z
B7Z
B8Z
B9Z
```

And so on, through to the final object on the sheet, "O9Z".

Currently a CommandButton_Click event is assigned button on the sheet that calls these (ugly) procedures, which are written as follows:

```
If Sheet2.Range("D12").Value = "A1Z" Then
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("A1Z").Visible = True
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("A2Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("A3Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("A4Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("A5Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("A6Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("A7Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("A8Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("A9Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("B1Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("B2Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("B3Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("B4Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("B5Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("B6Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("B7Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("B8Z").Visible = False
            Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("B9Z").Visible = False
```

I am able to simplify this bloated procedure *somewhat* using a For i statement:

```
If Sheet2.Range("D12").Value = "A1Z" Then
Dim i As Integer
For i = 2 To 9
Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("A" & i & "Z").Visible = False
Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("A1Z").Visible = True
Next i
```

One problem with my procedure however is that it will only affect the visibility of objects A2Z through A9Z without affecting objects B1Z-O9Z.

I believe it may be possible to add a second variable in addition to i that loops through each letter in a range "A", "B", "C", "D" and so on to letter "O" and adjust the For i statement to account for it, so that every object on the worksheet that does not match the value in quotes in the If statement (in this example, "A1Z") is hidden.

I am unsure of which method to employ to account for that range of letters however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looping through all the chart objects.

```
Dim cht As ChartObject
For Each cht In Sheets("Chart").ChartObjects
    cht.Visible = cht.Name = "A1Z"
Next cht
```

If you want the chart that is visible to be dynamic then:

```
Dim cht As ChartObject
For Each cht In Sheets("Chart").ChartObjects
    cht.Visible = cht.Name = Sheet2.Range("D12").Value
Next cht
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this using a for [each loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx):

```
Dim chartObj As ChartObject, strTest As String

strTest = Sheet2.Range("D12").Value

    For Each chartObj In Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects
        If chartObj.Name = strTest Then
            chartObj.Visible = True
        Else
            chartObj.Visible = False
        End If
    Next chartObj
```

A for each loop enables you to iterate through each object in a collection, for example you could do it for each worksheet in sheets